# Change UIImageView display/dimensions within a tableview cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, hide

I wanted to hide UIImageView within a cell of UITableview for specific cells based on whether image link is available for that cell row or not.

If a image url is not available from backend for a cell, then I wanted to "disable" UIImageview and reclaim its space for the label to expand. 
(UILabel is placed at left and UIImageView is placed at right corner.
Hence if there is no image, then I want the label text to expand to right if it has more text.)

I've tried two solutions: 
1. Change the width of the UIImageView to 0 by setting width constraint.

```
let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell.articleImageView as UIView,
                            attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width,
                            relatedBy: .Equal,
                            toItem: nil,
                            attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute,
                            multiplier: 0,
                            constant: 0)
 cell.myImageView.addConstraint(widthConstraint)
```

2. Remove imageview from the cell.

```
cell.myImageView.removeFromSuperView()
```

But as I scroll through and back, other cell's images also getting effected and getting hidden. Same for myImageView.hidden = true.

BTW, I use tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) for retrieving the cell. And the tableview and cell are created at storyboard.

Any help how to reclaim the space occupied by the hidden UIImageview within as cell, but not getting effected to other rows while scrolling?

Comment: can you post the cell for row method ? What you are doing is fine. Setting the width constraint to 0 should do the job. If other cells are affecting, then you are doing it wrong in cellForRow method.

Comment: let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell. Then loading image with AlamofireImage if theres a url, else making widthConstraint to 0. Alamofire crashes if width is 0 during scroll, but for width to some 20, Alamofire loads but all the other images are now width 20. Same effect for hidden = true. Reproducible without Alamofire. That means, any change to UIImageView affecting others there after. But.., If I do imageview.image = nil, then only that image is hidden, as expected(but I wanted to reclaim the image space).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding the constraint programmatically, assign the width in Interface Builder and create an outlet to the width constraint in your code.  Then, after dequeueing your cell you can change the width constraint's `constant` property to 0 if you want it hidden, or to whatever you want its expanded width to be.

Edit: Additionally I reset the constraint's `constant` property back to original size in `prepareForReuse()` method of the cell as suggested by @MuhammadZohaibEhsan in below comment.

Comment: Unfortunately, same effect with width constraint outlet to Cell. I think the Cells are getting reused and it effects the views and their structure if a view on any cell is changed. While not effecting the data of those views. But not sure how to retain the views as well while reusing cells (or may be Im completely wrong about reusing here).

Comment: Are you doing this in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`?  That should only be changing the image for that specific cell...it's also strange that Alamofire would be causing a crash if the imageView's width is 0.

Comment: Yes, Im doing at `override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`.

Comment: The tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier gives you a used cell. You should always make sure that after dequeue the cell is in its default state. Clearing all the changes and restoring its default state. prepareForReuse() is method which is called before reuse of a cell.Implement this method in your cell class and restore the default state.

Comment: Thank you Wyatt and @MuhammadZohaibEhsan. Your answers together solved my problem. Now I have to maintain the story board's imageview original Width value hardcoded in my code for resetting in Cell's prepareForReuse() - Its a bit annoying but will live with it for now. If you know how to get this imageView width of storyboard from Cell class, please let me know. Thank you for your time.